# PHP user-agent allowing to post on my site

Tags: php, user-agent

I have a voting site that my users can use to promote my game. When they click the voting link, it passes a variable called 'reference' to the voting site. If it is a valid vote (in the past 24 hours) it will then send a request back to my site with two variables.

```
$reference = $_POST['referense'];
$success = $_POST['success']; // 0 or 1
```

I've read that the user-agent must be changed to allow them to post things to my site? How do I let them do this? It is a valid voting site, so there is no need to be scared.

Thanks.

Comment: Why should the user agent to be changed? Do you want to secure a poll system or what is your aim?

Comment: Without knowing how they intend to post to your site we can't help.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: I just read that the site changed their user agent so I can detect it?

Comment: It sounds like your thinking about issues related to cross-domain, not user-agents [e.g. same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  If you can confirm the terminology or provide a link, you'll be able to get an accurate answer. Please provide some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you read is completely **wrong**.

User agents have nothing to do with. how a PHP code performs. And even if it does, ***IT SHOULDN'T***

---

You said that a reference is passed to the site, which is then sent to the voting system. So, your system should only check if the reference coming is a valid one or **NOT**. Not how the request is coming.

NOTE that, *User Agents can be spoofed so easily.* So, creating a system relying on such is very risky.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard such a thing. As long as you specifically are not filtering based upon user agent, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a user-agent could be at play here - if they are sending data to your site, it is up to you to examine the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

The way to post things to your site is by having a `form` submitted by pressing an `input` with `type=submit` like so:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" />
</form>
```

This should work, whatever the user-agent might be. You can replace the textbox with other input types such as a checkbox or radio button.

There are ways of sending a form with javascript, but i don't think that is very viable here.

Comment: Umm. I don't have a problem posting things to my site. It's letting them post to my site. Good try though.

Comment: then what is the problem? `I've read that the user-agent must be changed to allow them to post things to my site?` <-- from your question.

Comment: It is allowing them to post things back to my site from their site.

Comment: You are not going to catch that using the user_agent as that can be changed without much effort. You should be checking something more permanent/unchangeable.

Comment: Try to get something like mac-adress or ip adress and save that into the database and check each vote against anything in the database (you could add a timestamp to allow voting once a day/hour/week).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to to but you can read the User-Agent with this php code:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

If you want to secure a poll system you could "tag" a browser maybe with to combination of IP and User-Agent or also you could set a cookie on the system to prevent a second call.

But you have to know that these things can be fooled. You may add a login system which makes it a little more comprex for cheating.

Comment: I did that four times before posting.